# animation matrix in C

Tags: c, animation, matrix

Why does the animation work incorrectly when N > 5 or when there are more than 2 rows (that meet the condition 0)?
How can this be fixed or how can the animation be modified?

I understand that it may be due to the console window size or incorrect boundaries in the animation. How can the animation logic be modified to avoid such issues? I tried putting numbers on one line, but it introduces other problems with the right boundary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
void fillMatrix(int N, int matrix[][400]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 99;
        }
    }
    matrix[0][0] = 0;
    matrix[2][N - 2 - 1] = 0;
}

void printMatrix(int N, int matrix[][400]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%7d", matrix[i][j]);
            Sleep(200);
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
        Sleep(200);
    }
}
printf ("\n\n\n");
}
}

void startAnimation(int matrix[][400], int index, int N,
                    HANDLE hConsole, COORD position, int delta) {
    for (int iter = 0; iter < N; iter++) {
        if (index == 0) {
            for (int n = 0; n < N * 3 + 3; n++) {
                if ((matrix[index][iter] == 0 && index == iter) ||
                    (matrix[index][iter] == 0 && iter == N - index - 1)) {
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf("%d", matrix[index][iter]);
                    position.Y--;
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf(" ");
                    position.Y += 2;
                    Sleep(150);
                } else {
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf("%d", matrix[index][iter]);
                    position.Y--;
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf(" ");
                    position.Y += 2;
                    Sleep(150);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int n = 0; n < N * 3; n++) {
                if ((matrix[index][iter] == 0 && index == iter) ||
                    (matrix[index][iter] == 0 && iter == N - index - 1)) {
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf("\033[34m%d", matrix[index][iter]);
                    position.Y--;
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf(" ");
                    position.Y += 2;
                    Sleep(150);
                } else {
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf("\033[33m%d", matrix[index][iter]);
                    position.Y--;
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
                    printf(" ");
                    position.Y += 2;
                    Sleep(150);
                }
            }
        }
        position.Y--;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
        printf(" ");
        position.Y++;
        position.X++;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    
        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
            printf(" ");
            position.X--;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
            printf("%d", matrix[index][iter]);
            Sleep(200);
        }
        position.X += delta;
        position.Y = (index + 1) * 3;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsole, position);
    }
}

int main() {
    COORD position;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int matrix[400][400], array[400], i_index[400], N;
    int k = 0, m = 0, last_i = 0;

    printf("enter N:");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    fillMatrix(N, matrix);
    printf("matrix\n\n\n");
    printMatrix(N, matrix);
    position.X = 0;
    position.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    printMatrixColor(N, matrix);
    Sleep(600);
 
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (matrix[i][i] == 0 || matrix[i] [N - i - 1] == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("0 rows\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (matrix[i][i] == 0 || matrix[i][N - i - 1] == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                array[k++] = matrix[i][j];
                i_index[last_i] = i;
            }
            last_i++;//find last index
        }
    }
    printf("\narray");
    int delta = 11;
    position.X = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < last_i; i++) {
        position.Y = (i_index[i] + 1) * 3;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
        startAnimation(matrix, i_index[i], N, hConsole, position, delta);
        position.Y = (i_index[i] + 1) * 3 + 1;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    }
    position.Y += 2;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    position.X = 0;
    position.Y = N * 3 + 3 + last_i * 3 + 3;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    position.Y += 20;
    Sleep(200);
    printf("hello");
 
    printf("\n\n\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Don't tag both, only the language you're actually program in.

Comment: Two notes: That's a lot of code. I recommend building a [mre] to help you focus on the actual problem. The one character indent is only marginally better than a 0 character indent. Most eyes need more space to accurately judge the scope. Plus when you find yourself indenting so much that the code goes off the side of the page, you're probably doing too much in that function and should consider dividing up the responsibilities  better.

Comment: A bit of extra reading: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/4581301). I haven't checked to see if it really is called more than once, but placing `srand` in a function other than `main` means it could be, and you could be inviting bugs.

Comment: Remove all the non-essential code from your example (to make it more of a minimal reproducible example). Get rid of all the printf, Sleep, Console ans system calls.

Comment: By the way if you're going to want to write to a console consider using the ncurses library

Comment: `do { ... } } while(N < 2 || N > 400);` - You need to increase the warning level. The `while` part is actually outside the `main` function as currently written.

Comment: What is an animation matrix?

Comment: Sounds like you're bumping into windows console window size issues.  You can adjust the console rectangle/window size by making calls to [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) (to set the console buffer size) and [SetConsoleWindowInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) (to set the console window/rectangle size.)   When growing a window, you set the buffer size 1st or the call to set the rectangle size will fail.  The buffer must be large enough to accommodate the new screen rectangle.

Comment: That said, I got your code to compile and run and seems to animate nicely -- I like it!  It displays just fine, but I keep my console windows stretched pretty big by default:  120x54 ... so your code does just fine (imo) when the console is this size,

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, it isn't wise to declare `int matrix[400][400]` on the stack. This will chew up a significant amount of your available stack. Allocate this one in `.data` by making it `static` or alternatively allocate it dynamically.